How does one delete a tag?
I cannot find how to delete a tag. Is there a way for a non-administrator to do, or propose, it? (In particular, I'd recommend the removal of the “cli-fi” tag, presently used for a single question that is voted to be deleted, and it is unlikely that more questions on the same topic will arise.)

I Tag andrebbero cancellati tutti e riscritti in italiano. Fu un grande errore preferirli fin dall'inizio in lingua inglese. Italiani esterofili!

Maybe we should consider the possibility of adding Italian tag synonyms as in German.SE.

Tags not associated with any question are automatically destroyed at 03:00 UTC every day.
Tags which are misspelled should have the questions under them retagged to the appropriate tag, which will result in its destruction due to having no uses.

In fact, at this moment there is at least one tag that is misspelled: "etimology".

Thanks, @Charo, I retagged the questions.
